# Restricting the size of MNIST training data

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I have just started learning python and TensorFlow and am experimenting with various neural networks and the MNIST data. One experiment I would like to do is to see how the size of the training set affects the performance. Currently there appear to be 55000 input/output pairs in the training set. I would like some way of restricting the training to only use the first 1000 or so but have no idea how to achieve this.

My current training function looks like this:

```
def do_training():
    print("Train entry")
    for i in range(2000):

        batch_of_training_inputs, batch_of_training_labels = mnist.train.next_batch(100)

        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={generic_image_data_struct: batch_of_training_inputs, target_for_output_struct: batch_of_training_labels })
```

Is there something like...

```
mnist.train.next_batch(100, BUT_ONLY_FROM_FIRST(1000))
```

FYI, I get mnist with this code:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple thing you can do is just increase the size of the validation dataset. MNIST contains 60,000 images, so if you want to train on just 1,000 you can do:

```
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(train_dir, one_hot=True, validation_size=59000)
```

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of hacking, I think this might work. Although I **really** wouldn't recommend relying on this solution in the future since it depends on the internal implementation of `DataSet.__init__` method behaving a certain way. For a quick experiment, it might be fine.

```py
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist import DataSet
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
train_small = DataSet(mnist.train.images[:1000], mnist.train.labels[:1000],
                      dtype=dtypes.uint8, reshape=False, seed=None)
```